# Apache Spark 2.0 Dataframes (Dataset) group by multiple aggregations and new column naming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

1. Aggregating multiple columns:

I have a dataframe `input`.
I would like to apply different aggregation functions per grouped columns.
In the simple case, I can do this, and it works as intended:

`val x = input.groupBy("user.lang").agg(Map("user.followers_count" -> "avg", "user.friends_count" -> "avg"))`

However, if I want to add more aggregation functions for the same column, they are missed, for instance:

`val x = input.groupBy("user.lang").agg(Map("user.followers_count" -> "avg", "user.followers_count" -> "max", "user.friends_count" -> "avg"))`.

As I am passing a map it is not exactly surprising. How can I resolve this problem and add another aggregation function for the same column?

It is my understanding that this could be a possible solution:

`val x = input.groupBy("user.lang").agg(avg($"user.followers_count"), max($"user.followers_count"), avg("user.friends_count"))`.

This, however returns an error: `error: not found: value 
avg`.

2. New column naming:

In the first case, I end up with new column names such as: ``` avg(user.followers_count AS ``followers_count``) ```, ``` avg(user.friends_count AS ``friends_count``) ```. Is it possible to define a new column name for the aggregation process?

I know that using SQL syntax might be a solution for this, but my goal eventually is to be able to pass arguments via command line (group by columns, aggregation columns and functions) so I'm trying to construct the pipeline that would allow this.

Thanks for reading this!